# Search query returns an empty result set

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code :

PHP :

```
[CONNECT TO DATABASE OR DIE ( THIS WORKS )]   
if(isset($_GET['search'])) // If it's submitted 
    { 
    $inp = Clean($_GET['inpname']); // Clean my input 
    $sQuery="SELECT name FROM user WHERE (id LIKE '%$inp%')"; // mySql query 
    $r = mysql_query($sQuery) or die(mysql_error()); 
    if(mysql_affected_rows()===0) // If no match found 
        echo "{$inp} is not in our database."; 
    else 
        { 
        echo "<p>{$inp} was successfully searched.</p>"; // Yes, the query worked 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) // Loop through the query results 
            echo "{$row[0]}<br>"; // Show the results 
        } // End of the else statement 
    } // End of the if statement 

function Clean($str) // Clean my input 
{ 
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($sStr))); // Remove traces of injection 
}
```

HTML :

```
<form name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get"> 
<input name="inpname" type="text"> 
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"> 
</form>
```

I wanna search members in my database by ID but when I search for example 1 I have no results : is not in our database.  (/index.php?inpname=1&search=Search)

If I use '%".$inp."%' instead of '%$inp%' it's works but It's showing me all users from my database .

Comment: What is expected from `$_GET['inpname']` an int or a string eg a name, your script is also vulnerable to xss and PDO or mysqli should be used over the mysql_* functions.

Comment: your clean function has a typo `trim($sStr)` - **$sStr** when it should be just `$str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the php manual says:

> ```
> int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
> ```
>
> Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

So, no return values if you do a query with SELECT.

Change your code for something like this

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) // If it's submitted 
{ 
    $inp = Clean($_GET['inpname']); // Clean my input 
    $sQuery="SELECT name FROM user WHERE id LIKE '%$inp%'"; // mySql query 
    $r = mysql_query($sQuery) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($r))
    {
       while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
       {
           echo $row['name']."<br>"; // Show the results 
       }

    }
    else
    {
       echo "{$inp} is not in our database.";  
    }   

} // End of the if statement
```

if you want only one row

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) // If it's submitted 
{ 
    $inp = Clean($_GET['inpname']); // Clean my input 
    $sQuery="SELECT name FROM user WHERE id LIKE '%$inp%' LIMIT 1"; // mySql query 
    $r = mysql_query($sQuery) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($r))
    {
       $row=mysql_fetch_array($r)
       echo $row['name']."<br>"; // Show the results 
    }
    else
    {
       echo "{$inp} is not in our database.";  
    }   

} // End of the if statement
```

and if you want search by exact id

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) // If it's submitted 
{ 
    $inp = Clean($_GET['inpname']); // Clean my input 
    $sQuery="SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = $inp LIMIT 1"; // mySql query 
    $r = mysql_query($sQuery) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($r))
    {
       $row=mysql_fetch_array($r)
       echo $row['name']."<br>"; // Show the results 
    }
    else
    {
       echo "{$inp} is not in our database.";  
    }   

} // End of the if statement
```

Comment: Is not good . I can search any ID shows the first account only !

Comment: I changed this at the moment you are seeing :)

Comment: That's bad because the fisrt script you post was ok , now when I search 1 I see all accounts with 1 included . And I need only unique search . - Fixed : '$inp' :)

Comment: i have added all the posibilities

Answer (score 0):

I found out that searching with LIKE would work the best if you do:

```
id LIKE '%$inp%' OR id LIKE '%$inp' OR id LIKE '$inp%' OR id = '$inp'
```

because % means that there has to be at least one symbol. Thus %1% wouldn't find `1`, but would find `417`. At least this is what worked for me :)

Comment: http://www.123autotraffic.com/search_user/index.php?inpname=1&search=Search Show's me all users .